# pdfcomment including \vec: conflict when silence and newtxmath loaded

Tags: vector, pdfcomment, newtxmath, silence

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
    \pdfcomment{$\vec{x}$}
\end{document}
```

errors for me with the following message:

```
line 6: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \pdfcomment{$\vec{x}$}
```

Uncommenting any of the packages `silence` or `newtxmath` fixed the problem, but I need them. What can I do instead?

Thanks!

Edit: This problem is the result of using `latexdiff` on a modified equation. I am OK with the pdf comment not being perfect (even empty would be fine), but it should compile.

Comment: The [`pdfcomment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) README suggestions "sup­port of PDF an­no­ta­tions by PDF view­ers is sparse to nonex­is­tent".

Comment: ...why not just type `vector x` in the comment, since math is not allowed?

Comment: @Werner: Adobe supports it, this is enough for me. `vector x` would be OK if it could be replaced automatically. As I said, this file is created by `latexdiff`.

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{##1}\pdfcomment{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \DIFdel{$\vec{x}$}
\end{document}
```